# On button click make div visible if check box checked is true Using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 32 checkboxes (checkbox1,checkbox2,checkbox3.... checkbox32) and 32 div(div1,div2,div3.....div32) and one asp:Button.

On button click I need to make div1 visble if checkbox1 checked true and  div2 visble if checkbox2 checked true and div3 visble if checkbox3 checked true and so on using JQuery..

```
<div class="CheckBoxDiv ">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox1" runat="server"  />

    </div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox2" runat="server"  />

    </div>        .
                  .
                  .

<asp:Button ID="buttonShowData" runat="server" Text="Show data" class="ShowDataButton"  />

<div id="div1" runat="server" visible="false">
               ......
</div>
<div id="div2" runat="server" visible="false">
               ......
</div>
                    .
                    .
```

Comment: code/html or it didn't happen.

Comment: Nothing .. I am new to jquery... @ Explosion Pills

Comment: @Explosion Pills - I have added the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
    $(":checkbox").each(function (idx) {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $("div").eq(idx + 1).show();
       }
       else {
          $("div").eq(idx + 1).hide();
       }
    });
});
```

This goes through all checkboxes and shows/hides corresponding divs from all available divs.  It's highly likely that you'll want to use more specific selectors.